# Random swap DOM (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

My js is supposed to do a random swap of html elements. img or p for example. The position swap works but there is a bug I cant explain. in my example html are only 2 p elements. The swap works a few times but then a weird position change of the elements ensued.

```js
document.getElementById("pButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let max = document.querySelectorAll("p").length - 1;
  let min = 0;
  let x1 = Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
  let x2 = Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
  while (x1 === x2) {
    x2 = Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
  }
  let tmp1 = document.querySelectorAll("p")[x1];
  let tmp2 = document.querySelectorAll("p")[x2];
  let tmp1parent = tmp1.parentNode;
  let tmp2parent = tmp2.parentNode;
  let tmp1Index = 0;
  for (let a of tmp1parent.childNodes) {
    if (a === tmp1) {
      break;
    }
    tmp1Index += 1;
  }
  tmp2parent.insertBefore(tmp1, tmp2);
  tmp1parent.insertBefore(tmp2, tmp1parent.childNodes[tmp1Index]);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>List</h1>
  <p>p1</p>
  <ol>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
  </ol>
  <a>example</a>
  <p>p2</p>
  <ol>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
  </ol>
  <a>example</a>
</div>
<button id="pButton">BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: I think you're problem comes from this `let max = document.querySelectorAll("p").length;` As you are using an index which is zero based on these lines `let tmp1 = document.querySelectorAll("p")[x1];
let tmp2 = document.querySelectorAll("p")[x2];` It's possible you are going out of bounds with the index, try changing to this: `let max = document.querySelectorAll("p").length - 1;`

Comment: still not working with max-1, same bug

Comment: When does this position swap occur? From your example code it's not linked to an event listener or a timer.

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Comment: ok, thanks. I may create a jsfiddle so I can play around with this.

Comment: What is your expected behavior on this? That just the p elements switch places? Or that the p element and the following ol element with it's li elements switch places as well?

Comment: I created a fiddle so you, I and any others can work on a solution (https://jsfiddle.net/kryj7pn6/1/)

Comment: i want the p elements to swap position, but here the p element is going up if u use the button often.

Comment: Why not just swap their text instead of moving the elements? It would be much easier to do and probably fix your problem.

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle doing what I suggested to just swap their text, (https://jsfiddle.net/kryj7pn6/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we meet again :)

```js
document.getElementById("pButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let max = document.querySelectorAll("p").length - 1;
  let min = 0;
  let x1 = Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
  let x2 = Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
  while (x1 === x2) {
    x2 = Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
  }
  
  let tmp1 = document.querySelectorAll("p")[x1];
  let tmp2 = document.querySelectorAll("p")[x2];
  
  // it is nice to get direct reference, don't you think?
  let parentDiv = document.getElementById('parent');

  // get the previous element of first element you need to change
  let tmp1PrevEle = tmp1.nextElementSibling;
  // this is for the second one
  let tmp2PrevEle = tmp2.nextElementSibling;
  // insert both based on the previous and next elements
  parentDiv.insertBefore(tmp2, tmp1PrevEle);
  parentDiv.insertBefore(tmp1, tmp2PrevEle);
});
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <h1>List</h1>
  <p>p1</p>
  <ol>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
  </ol>
  <a>example</a>
  <p>p2</p>
  <ol>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
  </ol>
  <a>example</a>
  <!-- just to see the randomness, I've added two more elements -->
  <p>p3</p>
  <ol>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
  </ol>
  <a>example</a>
  <p>p4</p>
  <ol>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
  </ol>
  <a>example</a>
</div>
<button id="pButton">BUTTON</button>
```

What I did here,

1. Get the next element, from `nextElementSibling` and then run insert the element you need to shift.
2. I'm copying the `nextElementSibling` of both nodes so that they might not change in future.

Your issue is here.

```
let tmp1Index = 0;
  for (let a of tmp1parent.childNodes) {
    if (a === tmp1) {
      break;
    }
    tmp1Index += 1;
  }
```

this index is not reliable as once the items have been changed, original `nodelist`'s position might be affected.

Comment: @Joggi if the answer provided helped you, then accept the answer. It helps for other people with same problem to easily find the fix. And for others it means that your question got answer, and they can skip answering it.